# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory when running a CLI app

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I was coding a small CLI app and it works perfectly fine when running it directly using the "node" command, I added it to my PATH using "npm -g" and I also added the bin property on my package.json.

The command is recognized by my terminal, but it throws the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'classes.json'
```

classes.json is a file that I'm reading and writing to and it's on the same directory as the index.js file.

The command works when running it on the directory of my node project.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Try using an absolute path for classes.json.

Comment: Please share the folder structure containing the files index.js and classes.json as well as the code that is trying to load the classes.json file in the index.js. With that, I can help you solve your problem in 2 minutes.

Comment: @MestreSan This is my folder structure: 

project_dir/
├─ classes.json
├─ index.js
├─ package.json/

And this is how I read the file: 

const classes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("classes.json", "utf-8"));

Answer (score 0):

The `fs.readFileSync` looks for a file in the working directory of your shell, the one you are currently. If you are on a Unix-like system (Linux/Mac) or using Bash for Windows you can type `pwd` on your terminal to see your current directory.

Using an absolute path is not ideal because you don't know where that CLI will be placed on someone else's computer.

Although for JSON files this is not the approach I'd recommend, the way to fix your code independently where the files are could be something like this:

```js
const path = require('path')
const classJsonFile = path.join(__dirname,"classes.json")
const classes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(classJsonFile, "utf-8"))
```

For loading JSON files I'd recommend using the `require` function instead of fs then parsing the JSON. (assuming you are coding it in CJS not MJS)

```js
const classes = require("classes.json");
```

Much simpler and cleaner.